# Firefox not rendering HTML correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox

[image]

The picture shows the problem area I have with my website.  That little black line protrudes out from behind my dropdown menu and in Firefox the word `resources` will appear underneath `home`, but it IE and Chrome the menu looks as it should, except for that little black line that sticks out.  The template I'm using is a modified Dreamweaver template.  It didn't used to do this, but I breaked it :/

edit: all fixed.

Comment: A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will make your issue easier to understand.

Comment: I'll edit it to add the Jsfiddle link, thanks.

Comment: It is because of <hr> tag i think after #MenuBar1

Comment: sweet.  how did you know that was the problem so quickly?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Use firebug! ;-)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie There are tools that help design visualization for developers like Firebug (most famous), the Dragonfly (Opera). Look about. - Sorry for bad english -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your floats.

If you add `overflow: hidden` to your top menu UL and the sidebar div, you will notice the HR moves down.

**Edit**

Just an FYI, there is probably a better way to clear your floats then just adding overflow: hidden everywhere like I showed in this answer.  It really depends on how you are laying out the page, and I don't know what your plans are.  Therefore, here are some links below that explain what floats are, how they work, and how to clear them, which should give you a better understanding.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/